# Same value for different entities in Watson Assistant

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I have created a chatbot with IBM Waston Assistant with several questions having binary answers(Yes, No).
Eg: Would you like to share your feedback with us? (Yes/ No) 
    Are you comfortable with our environment (Yes/ No)
I need to recognize correct entity value(yes/no) for each question. Is there any possible way?

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible ways to go:
    1. Create two intents, e.g., "positive_answer" and "negative_answer" and provide examples like "yes", "yeah", "definitely", "I feel ok", "Yes, I want", etc. to train them (use "no", "I don't want to", etc. for the negative part). In your dialog tree, after posing the question react to the positive or negative answer appropriately.
    2. Do the same, but define entities like "positive_answer_word" or "negative_answer_word" and train and react accordingly.

You can reuse the same intent or entity for the different questions. Key is to react accordingly in a child node of the dialog tree.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. As you said i added two entities(@confirm , @tha1) and some dialog also. After train the chatbot it capture same entity for the both yes answers. its incorrect for my backend work. Am i missing something ?

Comment: its like this. Two entities - [@confirm] (values: yes, no) , [@tca1](values: yes, no)

In watson tryout panel it gives correct flow. The issue with me it select in correct entity. As flowing image it shows, always pass [@confirmation] as entity.

Expected answer 1st should be [@confirmation] and for second [@tca1]. but it gives both

Comment: You need confirm_yes and confirm_no, so that you can directly filter for that. How should the system, in your case, distinguish between the types of "yes"?

Comment: My system having a survey with several questions along with 5 yes, no questions. I need to save those yes, no values to database. I' m ok with saving different values like gender, age etc... But i need to save these 5 yes no values seperatly in my database columns.(5 columns) What i did was having 5 entiity values and save those to db. But having trouble with fitering the values. Is there any way to distinguish yes, no values seperatly

Comment: The tutorial https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html shows one of several ways to save answers to a database. Could you ask a new question on that topic?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single entity. Each question is separate, so you can just reuse that same entity for each one, but save it as a different context variable. Then just like in the tutorial linked above, you will save that same entity to multiple context variables, and when the session ends you can write the whole thing to your database.